# What could be the best way to avoid huge if elif statement which checks if a string contains

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having a huge if elif statement which checks if a string contains in input string? I want to get rid of this if else with a better way.

I have the below scenario

```
def check(input_str):
    if "AAA" in input_str:
        exec_aaa()
    elif "BBB" in input_str:
        exec_bbb()
    elif "CCC" in input_str:
        exec_ccc()
    else:
        default()
```

How can I implement this in a best way.

I know if it was equality conditions I could create a dictionary with `AAA`, `BBB` and `CCC` as keys and make the corresponding methods as  values. 
But how would I do this if the condition is like this?

Comment: How huge is "huge"?

Comment: you could maybe  use a dictionary like `{"AAA": exec_aaa, ...}`

Comment: (and are all the functions called `exec_*` or...?)

Comment: @Ev.Kounis : I already mentioned in the question that, if the conditions were checking equality with input_str, thenI could use the dictionary. But when the condition is not like that what to do?

Comment: @JonClements Huge like if something new comes I have to add it as a new elif. And yes there will be new conditions. Yes all will be calling different functions.

Answer (score 3):

The following should get rid of your long if else:

```
method_mappings = {"AAA": exec_aaa, "BBB": exec_bbb, "CCC": exec_ccc}

def check(input_str):
    for sub_string in method_mappings.keys():  # Loop through the sub_strings you want to check
        if sub_string in input_str:  # Check if the substring is in the string you passed in
            method_mappings[sub_string]()  # If a match is found execute its method
            break  # Since we matched we don't want to continue the loop
    else:
        default()  # If we exhaust the for loop with no match use the default
```

The trade off here is you will now have to manage the dictionary to map your options.

An update to take into account the comment by Ev. Kounis for python versions <3.7:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

method_mappings = OrderedDict({"AAA": exec_aaa, "BBB": exec_bbb, "CCC": exec_ccc})
```

Comment: Thanks, This could do it I guess

Comment: the problem is that you can control the priorities with the `if`-`elif` statements but not with the dictionary approach for Python3.7-. If e.g., both `"AAA"` and `"BBB"` match, you do not know what will be executed.. A list of tuples might be better still..

Answer (score 3):

cullzie's answer properly addresses your specific use case already, and is enough for most situtations. But there's another possible level of generalisation when the test itself is not uniform - for example if you have one case where it's a containment test (`substr in input_str`), another that only checks at the beginning or end of string (ie `input_str.endwith('x')`), etc etc. This generalisation consist in using a list of `(predicate, action)` functions, where `predicate()` encapsulate the test:

```
# example using lambdas as predicate but you can of 
# course use named function for more involved tests
rules = [
    (lambda inp: inp.contains("AAA"), exec_aaa),
    (lambda inp: inp.contains("BBB"), exec_bbb),
    (lambda inp: inp.endswith('x'), exec_XXX),
    # etc
    ]


for predicate, action in rules:
    if predicate(input_str):
        action()
        break
```

Comment: Thanks. This is more generalized one.

Comment: As mentionned, this is overkill for your current use case (at least as exposed in your question) which is already properly solved by the canonical `dict as switch` pattern posted by cullzie. I just thought I'd mention this more generic solution for peoples having a similar case as yours but with more complicated tests.